# Unable to link libssl to libcrypto

Tags: ssl, cmake, linker, pkg-config, rpath

I have created an application where it uses `libssl` which *apparently* uses `libcrypto`. I have kept these libraries at a user-defined location **`/path/to/xyz/lib/`**
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I have written a CMake for the application which links the libraries as follows:

```
set(GCC_LINK_FLAGS "-L/path/to/xyz/lib -lcurl -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl  //other libs")

add_executable(Foo ${APP_SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Foo ${GCC_LINK_FLAGS})
```

The **CMake didnot give any error** and created the Makefile which creates the **executable.**
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

But When I run the executable. it throws the below error
`./Foo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have checked the dynamic linking of libssl.so as follows and found the libcrypto isn't linked...

```
[root@localhost build]# ldd /path/to/xyz/lib/libssl.so.3
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa5fa7000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f17ea772000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f17ea556000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f17ea193000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563b0856f000)
```

I have checked the `/path/to/xyz/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc` file and found this suspicious for this error

```
prefix=/path/to/xyz/lib/
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenSSL-libssl
Description: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries
Version: 3.0.0-dev
Requires.private: libcrypto
Libs: -L${libdir} -lssl
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

**QUESTION**
What does `Requires.private: libcrypto` do?
And how to solve this error?

**--------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------**
I have Done following edits in the cmake file

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/path/to/xyz/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

add_executable(SpeechToText ${APP_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Foo ${GCC_LINK_FLAGS})

install (TARGETS Foo RUNTIME DESTINATION /path/to/project/directory)
```

I am getting **segmentation fault** by this change.

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /path/to/project/directory/Foo
-- Set runtime path of "/path/to/project/directory/Foo" to "/path/to/xyz/lib"
[root@localhost build]# ../Foo 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: The problem is about RPATH settings. You may adjust these setting using CMake variable, see [RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling). Or you may take any other answers to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library, which use **absolute paths** for libraries (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745)) - in that case CMake will automatically add RPATH which contains linked library.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and tried using `RPATH` but no luck. Please find the edited post

Comment: As you can see, the error message has been changed. Now it is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". It is no longer an error from the `ldd`, it is the error from the **your program** which is crashed.